# Datatable slow charging

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following table made with Datatables. It works great and is very pretty, the problem is that when it loads more than 800 - 1000 results it is very slow. There is also the problem that sometimes I can't avoid listing all that data at once. So how can I make it load faster? I have read that there are formulas to load (Through Ajax) from the server, but I don't know how to use them and if they will solve my problem. Thanks.

```
             if($lisc = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                 echo '<div class="card-body">';
                echo '<table id="html5-extension" class="table table-hover table-striped display " style="width:100%">';
                 echo '<thead class=""><tr role="row">
                 <th >'.$palabra['fecha'].'</th>
                 <th >'.$palabra['matricula'].'</th>
                 <th >Factura</th>
                 <th >'.$palabra['serieano'].'</th>
                 <th >Cliente pago</th>
                 <th >'.$palabra['base'].'</th>
                 <th >'.$palabra['iva'].'</th>
                 <th >'.$palabra['importetotal'].'</th>
                 <th>Cobrada</th>
                 <th>Ver Factura</th>
                 <th>Editar</th>
                 <th></th>
                   </tr> </thead>';
                  echo ' <tfoot>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                      </tfoot>
                    <tbody>';
                 do{
                   $baseventa += $lisc['base'];
                   $totalventa += $lisc['importe_total'];
                   $id = $lisc['id'];
                   $iva_cobrado = $lisc['iva_cobrado'];
                   $base_cobrado = $lisc['pagada'];
                   if($base_cobrado == 0 && $iva_cobrado == 0){
                     $cobrada = "Pte cobro";
                   }elseif($base_cobrado == 1 && $iva_cobrado == 0){
                     $cobrada = "Base";
                   }elseif($base_cobrado == 0 && $iva_cobrado == 1){
                     $cobrada = "IVA";
                   }elseif($base_cobrado == 1 && $iva_cobrado == 1){
                     $cobrada = "Cobrada";
                   }
                   $idpagador = $lisc['id_cliente_factura'];
                     $datos_cliente = new Clientes(intval($lisc['id_cliente']));
                   $cliente_pago = new Clientes(intval($idpagador));
                     echo '<tr role="row">
                     <td align="center" >'.cfechaguion($lisc['fecha']).'</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.$lisc['matricula'].'</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.$lisc['numero_factura'].'</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.$lisc['serie_factura'].''.$lisc['ano_factura'].'</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.$cliente_pago->nombre_comercial.'</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.round($lisc['base'],2).' €</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.round($lisc['importe_iva'],2).' €</td>
                     <td align="center" >'.round($lisc['importe_total'],2).' </td>
                     <td align="center" >'.$cobrada.' </td>
                     ';
                     ?>
                     <td>
                         <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href="<?php echo $rutaacceso ?>facturas/modifica_fra.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>">Editar</a>
                         </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <div class="btn-group">
                             <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="verPDFNavegador(<?=$lisc['id']?>,'factura')"><?php echo $palabra['verfactura'] ?></a>
                          </div>
                       </td>
                       <td ><button type="button" name="pagada" class="btn btn-success" onclick= "enviarFraiva('<?php echo $lisc['id'];?>','<?php echo $datos_cliente->email ?>','<?php echo $Config->texto_base_email ?>')">Enviar por Email</button></td>
                     <?php
                      echo'
                     </tr>';
                 }while($lisc = mysqli_fetch_array($data));
                 echo '</tbody>';
                 echo '<tfoot>
                        </tfoot>
                      </table></div></a>';
             }else{
                 echo "<h2  style='text-align:center'>No hay facturas emitidas.</h2>";
            }
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {



     var table = $('#html5-extension').DataTable({

         orderCellsTop: true,
         fixedHeader: true,

     "dom": 'B<"float-left"i><"float-right"f>t<"float-left"l><"float-right"p><"clearfix">',
     //"dom": 'Bfrtip<"lrtip"l>',
     "language": {
         "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
     },
         initComplete: function () {
             var api = this.api();

             // For each column
             api
                 .columns()
                 .eq(0)
                 .each(function (colIdx) {
                     // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                     var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                         $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                     );
                     var title = $(cell).text();
                     $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" size="8"/>');

                     // On every keypress in this input
                     $(
                         'input',
                         $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                     )
                         .off('keyup change')
                         .on('change', function (e) {
                             // Get the search value
                             $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                             var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();

                             var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                             // Search the column for that value
                             api
                                 .column(colIdx)
                                 .search(
                                     this.value != ''
                                         ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                         : '',
                                     this.value != '',
                                     this.value == ''
                                 )
                                 .draw();
                         })
                         .on('keyup', function (e) {
                             e.stopPropagation();

                             $(this).trigger('change');
                             $(this)
                                 .focus()[0]
                                 .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                         });
                 });
         },
         "ordering": false,
         "responsive": true,
        buttons: [
           {
             extend: 'copyHtml5',
             footer: true,
             text: 'Copiar',
             exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
            },
             text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i><span> Copiar</span>'
           },
           {
             extend: 'excelHtml5',
             footer: true,
             autoFilter: true,
             sheetName: 'Facturas emitidas',
             exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
            },
             text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i><span> Generar Excel</span>',
             filename: 'Listado de facturas emitidas',
           },
           {
             extend: 'pdfHtml5',
             footer: true,
             exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
            },
             text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></i><span> Generar PDF</span>',
             filename: 'Listado de facturas emitidas',
           },
           {
             extend: 'print',
             footer: true,
             exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
            },
             text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i><span> Imprimir</span>',
           }
       ],
       "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]]
     });
     $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
          table.draw();
      });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: "_sometimes I can't avoid listing all that data at once_" - Can you clarify why? A user navigates the table's data one page at a time. So, unless you force the table to have no pagination (all data is listed in one very long web page), then there may be no need to send all the data at once to the browser. You only need to send one page of data at a time (maybe 10 records, instead of 10,000 records) - which is the idea behind [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

Comment: On the other hand, if you need to print all data to Excel/PDF/etc., then it is better to use a server-side solution for doing that, for large volumes of data.

Comment: Well, if you think of it that way, it's true, you can list 10 by 10, for example, and calculate the totals on the server side. So the question would be... How can I do that pagination?

Comment: Take a look at server-side processing. See the above link for details on how it works.